# Bring Search to its original width when click elsewhere in page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$('#toggle').click(function myFunction() {
  $('.morphsearchinput').toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
.morphsearchinput {
  -webkit-transition: width .8s ease;
  -moz-transition: width .8s ease;
  -ms-transition: width .8s ease;
  -o-transition: width .8s ease;
  transition: width .8s ease;    

  min-width: 50px; /* min-width as the pixel value */
  width: 0%; /* width as the % value */
}

.expanded { 
  width: 80% !important; /* !important because min-width is stronger than width */
}

body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="morphsearch-form">
  <input class="morphsearchinput" type="search" placeholder="Search..." id="toggle" onclick=myfunction()/>
  <button class="morphsearch-submit" type="button">Search</button>
</form>
```

What is want to do is bring back the search to its original width (after expanding) when clicked outside input type i.e anywhere on the page .
But i don't know how to achieve that i can you javascript events but then how to define the area . Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: Could you just use the `:focus` pseudo-class?

Comment: I also want to change the height and position of my search box , like if i want to move it to the center of the page, i am using css transformation but not able to achieve exactly what i want to. Do you have any idea how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `click blur` events to get it working. 
I have also removed the inline `onClick` event, because you're bringing it using jQuery

```js
$('#toggle').on('click blur', function() {
  $('.morphsearchinput').toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
.morphsearchinput {
  -webkit-transition: width .8s ease;
  -moz-transition: width .8s ease;
  -ms-transition: width .8s ease;
  -o-transition: width .8s ease;
  transition: width .8s ease;    

  min-width: 50px; /* min-width as the pixel value */
  width: 0%; /* width as the % value */
}

.expanded { 
  width: 80% !important; /* !important because min-width is stronger than width */
}

body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="morphsearch-form">
  <input class="morphsearchinput" type="search" placeholder="Search..." id="toggle" />
  <button class="morphsearch-submit" type="button">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I also want to change the height and position of my search box , like if i want to move it to the center of the page, i am using css transformation but not able to achieve exactly what i want to. Do you have any idea how to do that

Comment: @raghavp Please create a new question with the new information and the issues you're having - I'll take a look at it

Comment: i have edited my question and code snippet  take a look

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these:

```js
var morphsearchinput = document.getElementByClassName("morphsearchinput");

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == morphsearchinput) {
    $('.morphsearchinput').toggleClass('expanded');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#toggle').focusin(function myFunction(){
  $('.morphsearchinput').addClass('expanded');
});

$('#toggle').focusout(function myFunction(){
  $('.morphsearchinput').removeClass('expanded');
});
```